# Conditional append a element to an array

Tags: jq

Here is the jq I have, it just wants to build a new element and then append it to an array,

```
[.[] | . as { foo: $foo1,  bar: $bar1} |
    {
        names: ([
            $foo1 | range(0;length) as $i |
            { key: ($foo1[$i]) }
        ] + [{ key: $bar1 }])
    } |
    {
    values: .names,
    }
]
```

And suppose I have a json like this,

```
{
  "foo":[
     "key1",
     "key2"
   ],
  "bar": "key3"

}
```

This will generate a json file like this,

```
[
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "key1"
      },
      {
        "key": "key2"
      },
      {
        "key": "key3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But the element should be only appended when the $bar is not an empty string, can I do something like this?

```
[.[] | . as { foo1: $foo1,  bar1: $bar1 if $bar != ""}
...
```

or do it when is appended,

```
        names: ([
            $foo1 | range(0;length) as $i |
            { key: ($foo1[$i]) }
        ] + [{ key: $bar1 }] | if $bar != "")
```

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `select` to filter out that case

```sh
jq '[{values: (.foo + [.bar | select(. != "")]) | map({key:.})}]'
```

If `.bar == "key3"`, it prints

```json
[
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "key1"
      },
      {
        "key": "key2"
      },
      {
        "key": "key3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If `.bar == ""`, it prints

```json
[
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "key1"
      },
      {
        "key": "key2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If `.bar` does not exist, it will print

```json
[
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "key1"
      },
      {
        "key": "key2"
      },
      {
        "key": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If in this last case you want to have the same result as with `.bar == ""`, then change `. != ""` to `values != ""` in the filter to consider only values that are not `null` (or to `strings != ""` to only consider (non-empty) strings and disregard any other type).

Comment: thanks, can I do it like this ```names:  ([ (\$foo1 + [\$bar1 | select(. != "")]) | range(0;length) as \$i | {``` so other part of codes won't be changed,  since the real case is much complicated than this, it needs to process multiple filed instead of just `key` here.

Comment: @jungler Generally speaking (i.e. depending on the accompanying code), yes.The idea is to first collect all values, and then do the structure. Nevertheless, your code (despite being a simplified version) has a lot of redundancies which most probably could be rewritten in a simpler, maybe even more efficient form.For instance, if the outermost structure is an array (which isn't shown in the sample but is addressed in the filters), then `[.[] | ‌…]` can be replaced with `map(…)`.Another one is `$foo1 | range(0;length) as $i | {key: ($foo1[$i])}` which is just a simple iterator `{key: $foo1[]}`.